# Creating dynamic variable in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, dynamic

I'm trying to generate a variable name based on day of week.  In my html.erb file, I have the following code:

```
<%= "@selected_venue.open_time_"+Time.now.strftime('%a').downcase %>
```

I'm trying to create a variable such as "@selected_venue.open_time_mon", "@selected_venue.open_time_tue", "@selected_venue.open_time_wed", etc.  As you can see, I'm appending the day of week to the generic variable name "@selected_venue.open_time_" so I can get the value of the dynamically generated variable.

Instead of getting the value that the variable represents (which is a time such as 2:00PM), I keep getting the literal result: "@selected_venue.open_time_wed".

Is there a method that I can use to get the value of the dynamically generated variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaner to move the logic to a helper, e.g.:

```
# in a helper
def open_time
  var = "open_time_" + Time.now.strftime('%a').downcase
  @selected_venue.send(var)
end

# in the template
<%= open_time %>
```

I agree with @Bubbles that it's better to have a collection like a hash or an array in `open_time` than having to metaprogram like this.

Comment: Mori - I ended up putting the open_time method into a helper and it worked great; however, I'm now calling the show action in my controller via AJAX and the application no longer recognizes the open_time method.  Do you have any suggestions on how to access helper methods via AJAX?

Comment: @Vee, the helper method should have the same scope whether called by AJAX or not. If the AJAX uses a different controller you need to make sure that the helper is visible there as well, e.g. with the [helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper) directive.

Comment: You're right, Mori!  After modifying a good amount of code, I forgot to rename the instance variable in the helper.  Again, works like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is more a [general ruby thing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send), but sure it's possible. You can access a variable like so:

```
@selected_venue.send(:"open_time_#{Time.now.strftime('%a').downcase}")
```

That said, in a situation like this I'd first consider if I could replace the dynamic variable with a hash - if `open_time` could be a hash and if you could set `:wed` on it, I'd personally find it tidier (of course, I don't know the full situation here - if you have seven variables in the venue table for daily opening times, this solution would make sense).

Comment: Thanks, Bubbles.  Your answer worked great but I went with Mori's answer below as it allowed me to insert some additional code in the helper.  Cheers!

Comment: Fair enough; there's a lot to be said for extracting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if `@selected_venue` is an ActiveRecord object (and `open_time_mon` is an attribute of that object), you can just use it like a hash:

```
@selected_venue["open_time_#{Time.now.strftime('%a').downcase}"]
```

Otherwise, as others have said you'll need to use send:

```
@selected_venue.send("open_time_#{Time.now.strftime('%a').downcase}")
```